# Need to sum from array object value in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to calculate total value if that value exits. But query is not working 100%. So can somebody help me to solve this problem. Here my sample document. I have attached two documents. Please these documents & find out best solution
Document : 1

```
{
    "_id" : 1"),
    "message_count" : 4,
    "messages" : {
        "data" : [ 
            {
                "id" : "11",
                "saleValue": 1000
            }, 
            {
                "id" : "112",
                "saleValue": 1400
            }, 
            {
                "id" : "22",

            }, 
            {
                "id" : "234",
                "saleValue": 111
            }
        ],

    },
    "createdTime" : ISODate("2018-03-18T10:18:48.000Z")
}
```

Document : 2

```
 {
        "_id" : 444,
        "message_count" : 4,
        "messages" : {
            "data" : [ 
                {
                    "id" : "444",
                    "saleValue" : 2060
                }, 
                {
                    "id" : "444",
                }, 
                {
                    "id" : 234,
                    "saleValue" : 260
                }, 
                {
                    "id" : "34534",
                }
            ]
        },

        "createdTime" : ISODate("2018-03-18T03:11:50.000Z")
    }
```

Needed Output:

```
{
   total : 4831
}
```

My query :

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$Id",

            "totalValue": {
                $sum: {
                    $sum: "$messages.data.saleValue"
                }
            }

        }
    }
])
```

So please if possible help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: Use unwind on the `data` array and then sum the `data.value`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not working correctly because it is aggregating all the documents in the collection; you are grouping on a constant `"_id": "tempId"`, you just need to reference the correct key by adding the `$` as:

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$tempId",
        "totalValue": { 
            "$sum": { "$sum": "$messages.data.saleValue" } 
        }
    } }
])
```

which in essence is a single stage pipeline version of an aggregate operation with an extra field that holds the sum expression before the group pipeline then calling that field as the [**`$sum`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) operator in the group.

The above works since [**`$sum`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) from MongoDB 3.2+ is available in both the **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** and **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** stages and when used in the **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** stage, [**`$sum`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) returns the sum of the list of expressions. The expression `"$messages.data.value"` returns a list of numbers `[120, 1200]` which are then used as the [**`$sum`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) expression:

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "values": { "$sum": "$messages.data.value" },
        "tempId": 1,
    } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$tempId",
        "totalValue": { "$sum": "$values" }
    } }
])
```

Comment: you query worked fine for my demo document. But not worked for my actual one. If I will share my actual data with you, can you check please ??

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check this & help me to figure out.

Comment: It's failing because `"saleValue"`  is a string, not a number. `$sum` doesn't work properly with string values, try to convert the fields to numerical values before running the pipeline.

Comment: Need just pageId as _id & total.

Comment: _But query is not working 100%_ Please show what you are getting as a result and the query you are using. Are you still using `"_id": "pageId",` in your `$group` pipeline step? If so, you need to change that to point to the correct key, like `"_id": "$pageId"`, as explained in the above answer if you were following. Also check if your MongoDB server version >= 3.2.

Comment: Is this possible to sum, if saleValue will string ? Can I cast this value for sum ?

Comment: @NazmulHossain As mentioned earlier in a comment above, it won’t work with string values. And you cannot cast to numerical values in situ during the aggregate operation. You need to change the schema first before running the aggregate pipeline to get the correct results or use mapReduce if otherwise

Comment: I am facing problem. As my production db already contains saleValue string, instead of Integer. So i am desparately fining a solution what will I do :(

Comment: is $literal help us for this ? can you please suggest ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `$unwind` before your `$group`, in that way you will deconstructs the data array, and then you can group properly:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
{
    "$unwind": "$messages.data"
},
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "tempId",
        "totalValue": {
            $sum: {
                $sum: "$messages.data.value"
            }
        }
    }
}
])
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : "tempId", "totalValue" : 1320 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
   {
     $unwind: "$messages.data",
     $group: {
        "_id": "tempId",
        "totalValue": { $sum: "$messages.data.value" }
     }
   }
])
```

[$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

Answer (score 1):

According to description as mentioned into above question, as a solution please try executing following aggregate query

```
db.myCollection.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: '$messages.data'
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    pageId: '$pageId'
                },
                total: {
                    $sum: '$messages.data.saleValue'
                }
            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $project: {
                pageId: '$_id.pageId',
                total: 1,
                _id: 0
            }
        }

    ]


);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without using `$group`. Grouping makes other data to be managed and addressed. So, I prefer using `$sum` and `$map` as shown below:

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
 {
   $addFields: {
      total: {
          $sum: {
            $map: {
              input: "$messages.data",
              as: "message",
              in: "$$message.saleValue",
            },
          },
        },
      },
    }, 
  } 
])
```