# Sum of a document fields mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate-functions

I need to find the sum of some specified fields using the following logic: Find document `where sum of (score_one.1+ score_one.2 + score_one.3 + score_one.4 + score_one.5) <= 6`.

The document structure looks like this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("5ce12e56937edb2b008631ec"),
    date: "2011-8-3",
    league: "American League",
    team_names: "Texas at Detroit",
    team_one: "TEX",
    score_one: {
        1: 0,
        2: 0,
        3: 0,
        4: 2,
        5: 1,
        6: 0,
        7: 0,
        8: 0,
        9: 1,
        T: "TEXT",
        R: 4,
        ML: -115,
        O/U: "",
        H: 10,
        E: 1
    },
    team_two: "DET",
    score_two: {
        ...
    }
}
```

How do I perform this query in MongoDB?

Comment: Please post sample document in JSON format. Images do not work here.

Comment: You can refer below link to achieve your solution here:
[click this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491235/need-to-sum-from-array-object-value-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're operating on a very specific set of fields, you can use the `$sum` operator on those specific fields. The `$addFields` stage adds any number of new fields to all documents in the pipeline according to the results of some expression. In this case, we perform a sum on the specified fields, prefixed with `$` to denote existing document fields, and store the result in a new `field_total` field. We then perform a `$match` on the modified documents to grab only the ones that have a `field_total` with a maximum value of `6` by using the `$lte` operator (less than or equal). The final pipeline looks something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$addFields: {
        field_total: {$sum: [
            "$score_one.1",
            "$score_one.2",
            "$score_one.3",
            "$score_one.4",
            "$score_one.5"
        ]}
    }},
    {$match: {
        field_total: {$lte: 6}
    }}
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution. I will try this and get back to you. (y)

Comment: Worked in this scenario but still trying to figure out your method in my application.

Comment: Ok i applied your solution and it worked with modification in my code. I have created a generic function using push() to array for the queries and then using find() method to get the result, However your solution was aggregation, so i shifted from find() to aggregation. It has no count() function unlike find(), but i ended up with toArray().length, dont know if that is a good approach or not. Thanks for the solution anyways

Comment: Marked your solution as Answered also up voted for nice explanation of your code.

Comment: Performing a `count` in MongoDB aggregation is simple for versions `3.4` and above: simply add one extra pipeline stage that looks something like `{$count: "my_count_field"}`. The `$count` will count all of the documents and store the result in the field you specify.

Answer (score 1):

Use $add in $project stage of the aggregation.

```
db.test.aggregate({ $match: {...your filter here... } },
     { $project : {
             'league' : '$league',
             'total' : {'$add' : [ '$score_one.1', '$score_one.2',... ]}
         }})
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zGarfdLr5zr)

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/zGarfdLr5zr - seems to work just fine. The answer from D Fleming adds final filtering on the total field.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort thumbs up

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve your solution from this link.[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491235/need-to-sum-from-array-object-value-in-mongodb)'s answer will guide you that how to aggregate and get the sum from particular array.